# Skipping lines when turning a text file into a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, text

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
word1   4
wöörd2   8
word3   12
word4   5
another word   1
many words one after another 1
word5   9
```

If it weren't for the lines with many words, the following code would work:

```
f = open("C:\\path\\words.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
dict = {}
for line in f:
    k, v = line.strip().split()
    dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()

f.close()
```

But obviously in the above case I get `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`. I assume there are three options:

1. Deleting it from the text file, which in a huge text file is difficult to do manually.
2. Skipping the line if such a problem occurs.
3. Modifying the code such that the value is always the last number.

I find 3. to be too daunting for a big, diverse (in terms of characters and words) file (especially since I don't care that much about the problematic lines). But for 2., how do I check if there are more than 2 elements when I perform the split of the line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to check. Just *catch the exception*:

```
with open("C:\\path\\words.txt") as f:
    result = {}
    for line in f:
        try:
            k, v = line.split()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:
            result[k] = v
```

Now the code will work for empty lines too, or lines with no spaces in between words.

Note that I made a few more changes:

- Using `with open(...) as f` guarantees that `f` will be closed when the block is done (whatever happens)
- Don't use the name `dict`; that's the built-in type you are now shadowing. I used `result` instead.
- No need to use `line.strip()`, `v.strip()` or `k.strip()` when using `str.split()` with no arguments; the latter already removes leading and trailing whitespace *from every split result*:

  ```
  >>> "   str.strip() \t    strips   \f  all  whitespace  \n".split()
  ['str.strip()', 'strips', 'all', 'whitespace']
  ```

You could make it a little more concise still by using the fact that `dict.update()` accepts a sequence of `(key, value)` tuples:

```
with open("C:\\path\\words.txt") as f:
    result = {}
    for line in f:
        try:
            result.update([line.split()])
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just asking about point 2, you can do this:

```
f = open("C:\\path\\words.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
dict = {}
for line in f:
    if len(line.strip().split()) == 2:
        k, v = line.strip().split()
        dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()

f.close()
```

As well if you're wondering about 3, and you know the last item is always a number you can index an array like this to get the last element:

```
f = open("C:\\path\\words.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
dict = {}
for line in f:
    if len(line.strip().split()) == 2:
        k, v = line.strip().split()
        dict[k.strip()] = v.strip()[-1]
    
f.close()
```

Comment: Thank you! However, I can't use the second code because sometimes the value is a big number, like 1967.

Comment: The second snippet of code will work for larger numbers, too. `split()` will split the string by spaces so if the last number is 1967 `v[-1]` will return the whole number

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you want to do, but it looks like the dictionary you are building always has the full sentence in a line as a key and the number at the end of a line as a value.
If the number is always going to be the last element on the line, you could do something like this:

```
f = open("C:\\path\\words.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
results = {}
for line in f:
    # select everything except for the last element, the sentence
    k = line[:-1].strip()
    # select just the last element, the number
    v = line[-1].strip()
    results[k] = v

f.close()
```

EDIT: best not to use the word *dict* as this is a method in python

Comment: This works, but strangely enough it messes up with my encoding, that is, the umlauts don't appear properly in the output. The same happened when I was trying to build the dictionary using json.dumps.

Answer (score -1):

You should change you code in a sense that from `line.strip().split()` you're not getting back key and value but a list.

```
f = open("C:\\path\\words.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
dict = {}
for line in f:
    splitted_line = line.strip().split()
    if len(splitted_line) <= 2:
        dict[splitted_line[0].strip()] = splitted_line[1].strip()
f.close()
```

Now, I will mention that if you do want to include lines with more than 1 word and a number you can achive that by concatinating the words with special character like _

using:

```
f = open("test.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8")
dict = {}
for line in f:
    splitted_line = line.strip().split()
    if len(splitted_line) <= 2:
        dict[splitted_line[0].strip()] = splitted_line[1].strip()
    else:
        dict['_'.join(splitted_line[:-1])] = splitted_line[-1]
f.close()
```